# Converting XML section that contains HTML to text using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

So my goal is to strip out the HTML code that sits within the `<email-description>` field, the data is an email body that has been exported from a CRM system, I want just the plain text left.

I can't show all the HTML as it contains sensitive data

**Example:** `<html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> <style type="text/css"> /*-------------------- Insert HP Font --------------------*/ /*REGULAR*/ @font-face{ font-family: 'HPSimplified'; src: url(http://h10180.www1.hp.com/hp-fonts/v2-0/hps-euro-w01-regular-eot.eot); /* IE9 compat */ src: url(http://h10180.www1.hp.com/hp-fonts/v2-0/hps-euro-w01-regular-eot.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */ /* non-IE */ url('http://h10180.www1.hp.com/hp-fonts/v2-0/hps-euro-w01-regular-woff.woff') format('woff'), /*IE9 and some modern browsers*/ url('http://h10180.www1.hp.com/hp-fonts/v2-0/hps-euro-w01-regular-ttf.ttf') format('truetype'); /*iOS, Android, Safari*/ font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; } /*BOLD*/ @font-face{ font-family: 'HPSimplified'; src: url(http://h10180.www1.hp.com/hp-fonts/v2-0/hps-euro-w01-bold-eot.eot); /* IE9 compat */ src: url`

**My XML file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<email-data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="">
    <emails>
        <email>
            <case-number>234-1234-1234-1234</case-number>
            <case-owner>Jimmy Choo</case-owner>
            <case-collection-date>01-01-2021</case-collection-date>
            <case-next-expected-activity>01-01-2021</case-next-expected-activity>
            <email-subject>Claim Return Notification</email-subject>
            <email-description>this field contains the html code</email-description>
        </email>
        <email>
            <case-number>234-1234-1234-1234</case-number>
            <case-owner>Jimmy Choo</case-owner>
            <case-collection-date>01-01-2021</case-collection-date>
            <case-next-expected-activity>01-01-2021</case-next-expected-activity>
            <email-subject>Claim Return Notification</email-subject>
            <email-description>this field contains the html code</email-description>
        </email>
    </emails>
</email-data>
```

**The following is the XSLT script I'm trying to use**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()[ancestor::field and not(self::text())]">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output desired should be the same as the import but with the HTML tags/code stripped out.

I'm using Saxon XSLT engine via java.

Unfortunately, no change happens to the HTML code, stays the same

Could someone lend a helping hand please

Thanks

Comment: Please add clarity to your question - I see no HTML in your xml, only text - perhaps just update your question to "how not to include this xml element" or some such
It would greatly help if you show what your desired output is as described in the site How To Ask instructions

Comment: What should your output be?

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tried to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Comment: I've updated my post with more information, thanks for the replies

Comment: If the posted answer doesn't work then we need to see an example of the sample XML with the HTML inside, delete any sensitive data but let us see whether namespaces or CDATA sections are involved. Also, as you use Saxon, which version and edition?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if, instead of

```
<xsl:template match="node()[ancestor::field and not(self::text())]">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

you want

```
<xsl:template match="email-description//*">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```